# How to unlock Dell Inspiron 15R N5110 BIOS hidden menu and possibly enable UEFI support

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, uefi, dell-inspiron

Apparently Dell decided for N5110 to use BIOS instead of UEFI,

but according to a user njoker [link](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/DELL-15R-N5110-UEFI-AND-SECURE-BOOT/m-p/3952738/highlight/true#M674740)
"IT HAS A RIDICULOUS LEGACY BIOS LAYER ON TOP OF A TIANO UEFI IMPLEMENTATION"

How to enable the hidden menu and possibly find a way to enable EFI support?

Comment: Back in 2012 it wasn't a matter of choice. The base hardware determined BIOS or UEFI. If UEFI boot was ever enabled in that mostly transitional firmware it would've come with a firmware update. Have you checked for and applied the last release? If so you should know better than random people in the internet.

Comment: The machine also needs Secure Boot, TPMv2 and a CPU less than 3 years old to run Windows 11.

Comment: @John see>>>https://makmodo.com/how-to-bypass-windows-11-requirements/